# RxJS groupBy to multidimensional array

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I've been attempting multiple combinations of operators and can't quite get the output I want.  Give an array of events:

```
const events = [
  { day: 1, title: 'Event 1' },
  { day: 1, title: 'Event 2' },
  { day: 1, title: 'Event 3' },
  { day: 2, title: 'Event 4' },
  { day: 2, title: 'Event 5' },
  { day: 2, title: 'Event 6' },
  { day: 'both', title: 'Sandbox 1' },
  { day: 'both', title: 'Sandbox 2' },
]
```

I'd like an output like so:

```
[
  [
    {
      "day": 1,
      "title": "Event 1"
    },
    {
      "day": 1,
      "title": "Event 2"
    },
    {
      "day": 1,
      "title": "Event 3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "day": 2,
      "title": "Event 4"
    },
    {
      "day": 2,
      "title": "Event 5"
    },
    {
      "day": 2,
      "title": "Event 6"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "day": "both",
      "title": "Shared 1"
    },
    {
      "day": "both",
      "title": "Shared 2"
    }
  ]
]
```

The only way I've been able to get this is by subscribing and pushing the result into another array.  Ideally the rx chain would build it before subscribing, but I can't quite get it.

Here's what I have that outputs the result above:

```
from(events).pipe(
    groupBy(obj => obj.day),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
  ).subscribe(next => {
    this.all.push(next)
    console.log(this.all)
  })
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a `toArray` operator after the `mergeMap`.

Comment: Perfect @cartant! I knew it had to be something simple. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accumulate the groups into an outer array, you can use another `toArray` operator after the `mergeMap`:

```
from(events).pipe(
    groupBy(obj => obj.day),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    toArray(),
).subscribe(results => console.log(results))
```

The resultant observable will emit only once and will emit a single array containing all of the group arrays.